# Laravel Eloquent multiple relationship in a football game schedule

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and Eloquent and i am trying to create a football game plan.
For now i have 4 tables (with some example entries):

### teams (all teams)

```
+---------+-----------+
| team_id | team_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Arsenal   |
|       2 | Chelsea   |
+---------+-----------+
```

### competition (all competitions)

```
+----------------+------------------+
| competition_id | competition_name |
+----------------+------------------+
|              1 | Premier League   |
+----------------+------------------+
```

### schedule (schedule to the competitions)

```
+----+----------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | competition_id | matchday | home_team_id | away_team_id | home_goal | away_goal |
+----+----------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |              1 |        1 |            1 |            2 |         3 |         2 |
|  2 |              1 |        2 |            2 |            1 |         0 |         3 |
+----+----------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

### schedule_teams (matches the schedule teamid with the teams id over the competition_id and the schedule_team_id)

```
+----+------------------+----------------+----------+
| id | schedule_team_id | competition_id | teams_id |
+----+------------------+----------------+----------+
|  1 |                1 |              1 |        1 |
|  2 |                2 |              1 |        2 |
+----+------------------+----------------+----------+
```

And here are my current classes:

### Schedule.php

```
public function competition()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Competition::class, 'competition_id', 'competition_id');
}
```

### Competition.php

```
public function schedule()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class, 'competition_id', 'competition_id');
}
```

With

```
$id = \request('competition_id');
$schedule = Schedule::where('competition_id', $id)->with('competition')->get();
```

i get the schedule with the home and away id's from schedule.
The question now is, how can i get the entries from the teams table over the schedule_teams table to a specifiy home and away id, also for example home_team_id = 1:
 home_team_id (=1) -> schedule_team_id (=1) and competition_id (=1) -> teams (Arsenal)

I want the data from schedule and the associated teams in a collection to output in a blade.

can anyone help or give me improvement tips for a football database?

Comment: Just as a note. It's widely considered best practise to have the primary key as `id` on your tables. So for example, in your competition table, you don't need `competition_id`. Otherwise it can get confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the `hasManyThrough` relationship.

If you create say `Schedule\Team`, and then have that like the following.

```
public function schedule() {
    $this->belongsTo(Schedule::class, 'schedule_id');
}

public function team() {
    $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team_id');
}
```

Now in your `Schedule` class, you can have the following.

```
public function teams() {
    $this->hasManyThrough(Team::class, Schedule\Team::class, 'schedule_id');
}
```

It should also be noted, that you don't need `competition_id` in your schedule team. Since a team belongs to a schedule, which belongs to competition, you can get it like that.

If you also want your `Team` to know about its schedules, you can add this to `Team`.

```
public function schedules() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Schedule::class, Schedule\Team::class);
}
```

You `Schedule\Team` class becomes essentially, a glorified representation of a pivot table, but having it as a model, allows you to expand upon it in the future. It also helps keep everything neat.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Great, it has put me on the right path! Thanks!
I edit teams() to hometeams() and awayteams() to get both teams, now i can get the home and away team with 
```$game->hometeams->first()->team_name```

Hope it is the right way 